# Reassign a Child to another Parent in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables, that are related in a one-to-many relationship.  I am trying to create a form where I can reassign a child to another parent.  For example, one table is Doctors (parent table), and the other is patients (child table).  I need to be able to have a form where I can select a record from the child table, then select a record from the parent table, and be able to assign/reassign the child to a new parent. All it will do is essentially change the foreign key in the child table.  I have looked everywhere and trying to see if there is an easy way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: *"All it will do is essentially change the foreign key in the child table."* Right. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I can't create a form to do this.  Even if I create a form with the record source as the Patients and subform with record source as the Doctors, I am unable change the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a Combo box on the Child Form whose Control Source is the Lookup to the Parent ID. The Row Source is something like this: 
    SELECT tblParent.ID, tblParent.ParentName
    FROM tblParent
    Order By tblParent.ParentName

Comment: Just tested it out and it works!!! thanks for helping me out on this!!  I figured it was something real simple but couldn't pin down what it was.